# Clip-on tuner signal analysis

Tags: matlab

I am new to this forum and I hope you guys can help me.
I am sampling vibration signals when I pluck a string from an electric guitar using a max4466(https://www.adafruit.com/product/1063) mic glued to the headstock.
I take 256 samples at 10kHz, but I expect that the vibration from the string to be less than 500Hz(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_vibration).
I am using MATLAB to take fft from the samples, but the relevant frequencies are not consistent.
Any suggestion about how to process the signal(I used some windows but those attenuate the signal a lot) or alternative methods(like correlation) to characterize the signal will be appreciated.
Thanks.

[image: Example sample]

Comment: Hi! So the plot belongs to the FFT magnitude of your string vibration data?

Comment: It's a sample from the vibration data

Comment: What device samples the audio, a PC sound card? If the peak happens to be at 128, could it mean there is a lot of aliasing?

Comment: The device is a Max4466 with an Arduino. I am not really sampling sounds, more like the vibrations from the guitar. A Pc sound card could be used with the max4466?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I take 256 samples at 10kHz,

I would recommend starting with a larger data set. It's much easier to see what's going on.

> I expect that the vibration from the string to be less than 500Hz

Even the fundamental of most guitars can go over 1 kHz (18th fret in the high E string). In addition to that you have the harmonics plus the transients from the plucking. So there is a LOT of action above 500 Hz. Keep in mind that for many guitars there is significantly more energy in the second or third harmonic than in the fundamental.

> Any suggestion about how to process the signal

Start with a good signal. Since you didn't label the axes (which is ALWAYS a good idea), I can't really tell what your graphs is supposed show but it sure doesn't look like a time domain guitar signal. There is a massive DC bias which shouldn't be there and the waveform  should have a clear string rest position. So for starters, make sure your signal is good. If need be, just record a few seconds and listen to it.

Good tuners are tricky. If you want at last 10 cents of resolution at 80 Hz (low E string), than you need about 0.5Hz of resolution or about 2 seconds of data. That makes FFT based algorithms extremely slow and memory inefficient.

Better choices are phase locked loops or delay locked loops, which can run continuously with limited memory and get better the longer they run.

Comment: I use an Arduino UNO to sample and record the samples(0-1023 ADC), the bias is because it is imposed by the max4466 (bias=VCC/2) but I that into consideration when I apply the fft. Maybe using an arduino is not the best option?